# php code into a leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I have a map with markers. Each marker has a popup with its name, its id .. (a marker is a dam).

When a user of the website is not authentified, it works like this : [link to my website](https://tbmigrateurs.eptb-vienne.fr/)

My popup is created with javascript :

```
    var fiche ="
<div class='fiche'>";
    fiche+= "
    <p class='elementFiche'>
        <strong>" + propriete + "</strong>"+  " : " + valeur + '
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>"
    marker.bindPopup(fiche);
```

When a user is identified, I would like to make confidential information available.

In a simple html page I did that :

included in index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in']==true ){
    include(EditionMode.php);
    };
    ?>
```

EditionMode.php

```
<p> You are in Edition Mode </p>
```

Now I would like to do it in the popup.
I tried it like this :

```
              var fiche ="
<div class='fiche'>";
    var fiche += 
    <?php session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in']==true ){ echo 'confidential information'};?>
    fiche+= "
    <p class='elementFiche'>
        <strong>" + propriete + "</strong>"+  " : " + valeur + '
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>"
    marker.bindPopup(fiche);
```

My question is « Is there a way to put php code in a leaflet popup instead of simple html ? »
If not, does someone has another solution ?

I thought perhaps I should create 2 elements and associate the right element to the marker, as a popup, depending if the user is authentified or not.

**EDIT**
For the moment I implemented another solution to avoid the problem (perhaps this one is better ..). When the file is loaded, I check if the user if authentified or not using AJAX. Then when I create the popup, I add confidential information only if the user is authentified.

my AJAX call

```
/////////////////
//check if user is authentified
var auth = new XMLHttpRequest();
auth.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
console.log("authentification vérifiée");
authentified = this.responseText;
console.log("rep",this.responseText);
}
}
auth.open("GET", "checkSession.php", true);
auth.send();
```

checkSession.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in']==true ){
echo (true);
}
else {echo (false);}
?>
```

My js function which create my popup :

```
 <div class='fiche'>";
if ((champsConfidentiels.includes(propriete) && authentified==1) ||     champsConfidentiels.includes(propriete)==false ){
    fiche+= "
    <p class='elementFiche'>
        <strong>" + propriete + "</strong>"+  " : " + valeur + '
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>"
    marker.bindPopup(fiche);
```

This works fine :)

Comment: It could be easier if you generate the popups using AJAX, because you could use pure PHP then

Comment: But I have lots of popups .. The solution I found to avoid my problem is to check if the user is authentified using AJAX, when page is loaded. Then I plot confidential information if authentified = true. Perhaps it is the simplest way.

Comment: If the confidential information is already available in the JS file, how can you call that data "confidential"?

Comment: I don't see what you mean so I edited my code to show you what I did.

Comment: Since you have answered and fixed your own question, maybe you could post your edit as an answer so this question can be marked as resolved. And yes, the second way is better than the first way.

Comment: I was waiting to know if it was better or not. I am trying to use Voros Amadea solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var fiche += <?php if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in']==true ){ 
echo 'confidential information'};?>
```

**Try this:**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] === true){ ?>
var fiche += 'confidential information';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's php code while my file is js so I can't.

Comment: I tried and it works (using = instead of +=) indeed !

Comment: So thank you for the solution but it seems to me that the second solution I used (the one in my EDIT) finally works better, do you agree ?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented another solution to avoid the problem, but it seems that it is better this way than the way I was trying, so good news ! 
I publish it if someone needs, but the solution of Voros Amadea works also. It resolved my problem which was to publish php code in my popup.

My other solution is this one : when the file is loaded, I check if the user if authentified or not using AJAX. Then when I create the popup, I add confidential information only if the user is authentified.

my AJAX call

```
/////////////////
//check if user is authentified
var auth = new XMLHttpRequest();
auth.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
console.log("authentification vérifiée");
authentified = this.responseText;
console.log("rep",this.responseText);
}
}
auth.open("GET", "checkSession.php", true);
auth.send();
```

checkSession.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in']==true ){
echo (true);
}
else {echo (false);}
?>
```

My js function which create my popup :

```
 <div class='fiche'>";
if ((champsConfidentiels.includes(propriete) && authentified==1) ||     champsConfidentiels.includes(propriete)==false ){
    fiche+= "
    <p class='elementFiche'>
        <strong>" + propriete + "</strong>"+  " : " + valeur + '
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>"
    marker.bindPopup(fiche);
```

This works fine :)